# Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable in javascript module

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have declared a variable in one module like this:

```
// first.js

var folder;
export {folder};
```

and I want to use it from a different module, like this:

```
// second.js

import { folder} from '../js/first.js';
folder = gui.addFolder( 'Avatar Measurements' );`
```

`TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Answer (score 2):

Imports are read-only live bindings to the original variable in the exporting module. The "read-only" part means you can't directly modify them. The "live" part means that you can see any modifications made to them by the exporting module.

If you have a module that needs to allow other modules to modify the values of its exports (which is/should be *rare*), it needs to export a function that does that. For instance:

`a.js`:

```
export let folder;
export function setFolder(f) {
    folder = f;
}
```

`b.js`:

```
import { folder, setFolder } from "./a.js";

console.log(folder); // This will be `undefined` unless another module has already modified it
setFolder(gui.addFolder("Avatar Measurements"));
console.log(folder); // This will be whatever `gui.addFolder` returns
```

Again, though, it is/should be very rare for a module to allow other modules to modify its exports that way.

---

In the comments you asked me for an example of exporting an object for this instead:

`a.js`:

```
export let shapes = {};
```

`b.js`:

```
import { shapes } from "./a.js";

shape.folder = gui.addFolder("Avatar Measurements");
```

But it's not clear to me why that object needs to live in `a` rather than just being local in `b`.

Comment: there are so many variable, it will be good to wight all like this?. or there is any other syntex. for now this is the code folder == gui.addFolder( 'Avatar Measurements' );
   upper == gui.addFolder( 'Upper Measurement' );
   lower == gui.addFolder( 'Lower Measurement' );
   reset == gui.add( params, 'reset' ).name("Reset");
   save == gui.add( params, 'save' ).name("Save avatar");

Comment: @Deepak3301086 - To me, that sounds like you need to change your module structure. It's not clear to me why you have one module exporting the variables and another module trying to change them. That's a bit of a red flag. But it's hard to suggest an alternative without having more context. Alternatives include exporting a mutable object, or having the module that's doing the modifying own the variables, or...

Comment: Thanks for reply quiclky, I have 14 shapes and every shape defined in one module. and in a common module i declared variables and try to used those in all module.

Comment: its like one shape have different measurement and second shape have different measurement, etc. so i have used measurement as common and fill value in different modules.

Comment: @Deepak3301086 - It sounds like you want an object, not individual variables, but again from that description it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Yes, because for now i need to export almost 20 variables from one module to another.

Comment: it will be helpful if you give me any idea of how to use object in place of assigning multiple variables in common modules and use it in all different shape by export and import

Comment: For batter understand my requirement, It is like i declared a variable a and fill its value in every new module and take output.

Comment: @Deepak3301086 - Why not just use local variables in the modules then? Why would you need to get them from elsewhere?

Comment: Ok, if no way then i will do like this way, Thanks for help.

Comment: @Deepak3301086 - I've added an example of exporting and using an object, but I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Sorry about that. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are creating a `folder` constant when importing `folder` from `../js/first.js`. You cannot reassign a value to any constant, including `folder`. *Don't use `==` or `===`, as those are comparasion operators and don't change the value of `folder`.*

If you want to pass information from `second.js` to `first.js`, consider exporting a function from `second.js`. If you don't, then use another name for a variable, like `folder_` (don't forget to declare it first: `var folder_;`).

Comment: I do not want to reassign it, Please let me know how to get folder in second.js without importing. Yes i have passed information from second to first.js

Comment: What do you want to do, then?

Comment: I have 14 human body shape and every body have different measurement. so it is like I have defined a variable measurement, and used it in every shape. and display output of selected shape in common module.